# Managing browser sessions with Google sign in

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api, authentication, oauth, google-signin

I have implemented a google sign in button for my website using the steps outlined in this page:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

The page then extracts the id_token and sends it to my backend server, which validates it against the Google validation endpoint.  I then use their Google ID that is encoded in the id_token to retrieve the application specific data associated with it (stored on my database).

I'm just a bit confused on what I need to do next to keep the user "signed in" to my application and to continue to securely retrieve data from my backend API's.

I am intending to do the following:

1. After I have validated the id_token I create a session ID for the user
2. I store the session ID along with the users Google ID in a "sessions" table in my database
3. I respond to the request by setting a cookie with the session ID
4. For all subsequent requests I check the session ID in the cookie
5. If there is an entry for that session ID in the sessions table, I use the Google ID associated with it to retrieve the users info

I would just like to know if this sounds reasonable, is it best practice or if there is a better way to do this?  Is there are secure way to generate session ID's or are there API's to help with this (I am currently using ASP.Net Web Api 2 for my backend services)

Many thanks,

Comment: Thank you for your clear, well-outlined question on this thoroughly unaddressed topic!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing authentication and authorization. You should have your own record of the user in your server app and the key is Google, not the "name". Here's what I do in my Django (Python) application:

```
def auth_id_token(request):
    # This is called by the AJAX code that triggers when 
    # the user has successfully signed in
    id_token = request.POST.get('id_token')
    # Using the google-api-python-client library
    idinfo = client.verify_id_token(
        id_token,
        settings.OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID
    )
    # Use the Django ORM to talk to my user database
    user = User.objects.get(email=idinfo['email'])
    # Using a Django primitive that makes sure the user
    # gets a session cookie and asserts that the user is now signed in
    auth.login(request, user)
    return http.HttpResponse('User is now signed in on the server')
```

Note. Django handles all the authorization from this point onwards. Google was just there to handle the **authentication** that proves to me that he/she owns that email address.

Comment: after the user signs in, do I need to send the token in **all** subsequent calls to my server (Java Spring) so I can verify the user is signed in and can access protected resources? Thanks!